# Problems with MySQL COUNT() and joins

Tags: mysql, join

I need to get a count of which types of tickets have been ordered on each account, and only on accounts that have incurred a transaction. I'm doing this with the following query for each price:

```
SELECT tickets.order_id as order_id, count(tickets.id) as count 
  FROM tickets,transactions 
  WHERE price = $price 
    AND tickets.order_id = transactions.order_id 
  GROUP BY tickets.order_id
```

This gets the right set of results, but on orders where there are multiple transactions the number for count(tickets.id) is multiplied by that number. What query do I need to use to avoid this problem? Do I need to use a different kind of join?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use

```
count (distinct tickets.id)
```

Comment: Cheers, thought it might be something like that but didn't know you could use the `distinct` keyword in that context, thanks!